# Multiple XmlElements referencing to the same property in c#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

I have following two files and Because both files having the same structure, I would like to keep one class and refer it multiple times.

XML File1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<TRANSFERS>
    <TR_DOCTOR_MR>
        <REFDOC_CODE>MR Code</REFDOC_CODE>
        <REFDOC_HOSPITALKEY>Hospital 1</REFDOC_HOSPITALKEY>
        <REFDOC_RIZIV>Riziv 1</REFDOC_RIZIV>
        <REFDOC_NAME>Name 1</REFDOC_NAME>
        <REFDOC_FNAME>FName 1</REFDOC_FNAME>
        <REFDOC_TITLE>Mr.</REFDOC_TITLE>
        <REFDOC_INITIALS>RI11</REFDOC_INITIALS>
        <REFDOC_FREEFIELD1>FF1</REFDOC_FREEFIELD1>
        <REFDOC_FREEFIELD2>FF2</REFDOC_FREEFIELD2>
        <REFDOC_FREEFIELD3>FF3</REFDOC_FREEFIELD3>
    </TR_DOCTOR_MR>
</TRANSFERS>
```

XML File2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<TRANSFERS>
    <TR_DOCTOR_RESP>
        <ATDOC_CODE>Ref Doctor</ATDOC_CODE>
        <ATDOC_HOSPITALKEY>Hosp 2</ATDOC_HOSPITALKEY>
        <ATDOC_RIZIV>Riziv 2</ATDOC_RIZIV>
        <ATDOC_NAME>Name 2</ATDOC_NAME>
        <ATDOC_FNAME>FName 2</ATDOC_FNAME>
        <ATDOC_TITLE>Mr.</ATDOC_TITLE>
        <ATDOC_INITIALS>AI22</ATDOC_INITIALS>
        <ATDOC_FREEFIELD1>FF1</ATDOC_FREEFIELD1>
        <ATDOC_FREEFIELD2>FF2</ATDOC_FREEFIELD2>
        <ATDOC_FREEFIELD3>FF3</ATDOC_FREEFIELD3>
    </TR_DOCTOR_RESP>
</TRANSFERS>
```

Here is the C# code:

```
[XmlRoot("TRANSFERS")]
public class TransferXml
{
    [XmlElement("TR_DOCTOR_MR")]
    public TransferDoctorXml TR_DOCTOR_MR { get; set; }
    
    [XmlElement("TR_DOCTOR_RESP")]
    public TransferDoctorXml TR_DOCTOR_RESP { get; set; }
}

public class TransferDoctorXml
{
    [XmlElement("ATDOC_CODE")]
    [XmlElement("REFDOC_CODE")]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ATDOC_HOSPITALKEY")]
    [XmlElement("REFDOC_HOSPITALKEY")]
    public string HospitalKey { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ATDOC_RIZIV")]
    [XmlElement("REFDOC_RIZIV")]
    public string Riziv { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ATDOC_NAME")]
    [XmlElement("REFDOC_NAME")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ATDOC_FNAME")]
    [XmlElement("REFDOC_FNAME")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ATDOC_TITLE")]
    [XmlElement("REFDOC_TITLE")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ATDOC_INITIALS")]
    [XmlElement("REFDOC_INITIALS")]
    public string Initials { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ATDOC_FREEFIELD1")]
    [XmlElement("REFDOC_FREEFIELD1")]
    public string FreeField1 { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ATDOC_FREEFIELD2")]
    [XmlElement("REFDOC_FREEFIELD2")]
    public string FreeField2 { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ATDOC_FREEFIELD3")]
    [XmlElement("REFDOC_FREEFIELD3")]
    public string FreeField3 { get; set; }
}
```

I want both files refer to the same C# class for deserialization to avoid duplicates and have code clean and maintainable. However, it doesn't work like this. I have googled a lot to find out if this is possible. But couldn't find it. Can anyone please help me?

```
string DoctorMr = File.ReadAllText("C:\\TEMP\\TransferDoctorMr.xml");
TransferXml drXml = XmlHelper<TransferXml>.DeserializeObject(DoctorMr);
```

Thank you.

Comment: You need to use a Steam, not a string.  So use : StringReader reader = new StreamReader(DoctorMr);  XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof( TransferXml)); TransferXml transers = (TransferXml)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

Comment: Nope.. It didn't work. My problem is that if I use two different XmlElement specify for a property then it throws the following exception:

InvalidOperationException: You need to add XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute to the 'Code' member.

Comment: I 'm not sure what mlChoiceIdentifierAttribute is referring to.  There is a schema and the schema check is failing.  The schema must say that the attribute is required and is missing.  Or it may need to be an Attribute instead of a Element.

Comment: I cannot have it as Attribute. It must be XML Element. I am not able to refer to multiple Xml Element on the common class properties.